# Groupby Date Produces Blank DataFrame - Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How do I group by date?

I've tried `df.grouby(df.date)` and it produces a blank df. Essentially I want the NaNs removed and values 1 and values 2 grouped by date.

```
         date  value1 value2
0  2001-01-01   800 NaN
1  2001-01-02   900 NaN
2  2001-01-03  1200 NaN
3  2001-01-04   700 NaN
4  2001-01-05   600 NaN      
5  2001-01-01   NaN 1175
6  2001-01-02   NaN 1176
7  2001-01-03  NaN 1177
8  2001-01-04   NaN 1778
9  2001-01-05   NaN 1779
```

Desired DataFrame:

```
         date  value1 value2
0  2001-01-01   800 1175
1  2001-01-02   900 1176
2  2001-01-03  1200 1177
3  2001-01-04   700 1778
4  2001-01-05   600 1179
```

Comment: what do you mean you want NaNs removed? What do you want to show instead? You want only one column?

Comment: If you want `NaN` rows removed then all rows will be removed right ending up with empty dataframe?

Comment: @Snow,  please see edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html):

```
new_df = df.groupby('date',as_index = False).first()
print(new_df)

         date  value1  value2
0  2001-01-01   800.0  1175.0
1  2001-01-02   900.0  1176.0
2  2001-01-03  1200.0  1177.0
3  2001-01-04   700.0  1778.0
4  2001-01-05   600.0  1779.0
```

---

If you can have more than one value per column and date then you need:

```
df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()).drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) which by default drops the `nan` followed by [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df.set_index('date').stack().unstack().reset_index()
```

---

```
         date  value1  value2
0  2001-01-01   800.0  1175.0
1  2001-01-02   900.0  1176.0
2  2001-01-03  1200.0  1177.0
3  2001-01-04   700.0  1778.0
4  2001-01-05   600.0  1779.0
```

Comment: This returns: `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: @Starbucks I see , works for the example, try `df.pivot_table(index='date',aggfunc='first').reset_index()` , or even ansev solution works fine. Else you should show us more of your data